# Can't Express Function into Keras Custom Objective

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, keras

I'm writing a model that predicts 15 time steps in advanced. When I use Mean Squared Error as an objective, it's really good at getting that first time step close, but then it is able to slack on the other ones without enough effect to the overall error, so I want to write an objective that applies an exponential to each degree so that changes in the 15th step are more significant to the overall error to the power of 15. I think this will incentive the model to explore more options than giving up so soon.

Also, I want to clamp the data between 0 and 1 so that it error is relatively calculated. Thus, this should dynamically adjust the error as it begins to learn and get closer and closer to the correct values.

However, working with the symbolic tensor variables in Theano / Keras's back-end is literally a nightmare.

My code looks like this, and I am having a really hard time translating this into something that uses the symbolic variables.

```
def relative_exponential_degree_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    true_arr = K.get_value(y_true)
    pred_arr = K.get_value(y_pred)

    max_scalar = K.maximum(y_true, y_pred)
    min_scalar = K.minimum(y_true, y_pred)

    for x in xrange(len(true_arr)):
        if max_scalar == min_scalar:
            true_arr[x] = 0.5
            pred_arr[x] = 0.5
        else:
            true_arr[x] = (true_arr[x] - min_scalar) / (max_scalar - min_scalar)
            pred_arr[x] = (pred_arr[x] - min_scalar) / (max_scalar - min_scalar)

    error_tensor = []
    for x in xrange(len(true_arr)):
        error_tensor.append(abs(pred_arr[x] - true_arr[x])**(x+1))

    return np.array(error_tensor)
```

The closest I've gotten is this, except that the error is always one, and then it hits NAN after about 60 epochs:

```
def relative_exponential_degree_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    norm_true = ((y_true - K.minimum(y_true, y_pred)) / (K.maximum(y_true, y_pred) - K.minimum(y_true, y_pred)))
    norm_pred = ((y_pred - K.minimum(y_true, y_pred)) / (K.maximum(y_true, y_pred) - K.minimum(y_true, y_pred)))
    error = K.square(norm_pred - norm_true)

    return K.mean(error, axis=-1)
```

Any help?